# How to remove a list value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary with lists as values.

```
myDict = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 3: [], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 5: [], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
```

How can I remove items from the dictionary if the value list is empty?

I tried to iterate over the dictionary and remove items, but the dictionary size is not allowed to change during iteration.

```
for item in myDict:
    if myDict[item] == []:
        print item
        del myDict[item]
```

Comment: I love python. It is so powerful! Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using dict comprehension:

```
>>> myDict = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 3: [], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 5: [], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
>>> myDict = {k: v for k, v in myDict.items() if v}
>>> myDict
{0: [0, 1, 2], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
```

---

Adding, deleting dictionary entries are not allowed while iterating it. Make a copy of keys to overcome it. For example, in the following, I used `tuple(myDict)` to get copy of the keys.

```
>>> myDict =  {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 3: [], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 5: [], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
>>> for item in tuple(myDict):
...     if myDict[item] == []:
...         del myDict[item]
...
>>> myDict
{0: [0, 1, 2], 2: [20, 25, 26, 28, 31, 34], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10], 6: [10, 20, 24]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in myDict.keys():
  if myDict[k] == []:
    del myDict[k]
```

This will remove any key for which the value is and empty array.

Comment: I added a +1, but then decided to remove it because of the 2-spaces indentation

Comment: This works in Python 2.x, but not in Python 3.x. Because, in Python 3.x, [dict.keys](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a view of the keys instead of the list.